# In clojure, how to reverse a map hierarchy

Tags: clojure

In `clojure`, I have a map that contains for each day, and each fruit, the number of fruits eaten. I would like to "reverse the hierarchy" of the map and to return the same data but with the fruits at the top of the hierarchy.

I will explain by an example:

```
(map-reverse-hierarchy {:monday {:banana 2 :apple 3} 
                        :tuesday {:banana 5 :orange 2}})
; => {:orange {:tuesday 2},
;     :banana {:tuesday 5, :monday 2},
;     :apple {:monday 3}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution first transposes the pieces of the nested maps and then merges them all.

The pieces are transposed from `{k1 {k2 v}}`to `{k2 {k1 v}}` and then merged by `apply merge-with conj`

```
(defn map-reverse-hierarchy [mm]
   (apply merge-with conj
     (for [[k1 m] mm [k2 v] m] {k2 {k1 v}})))
```

Comment: I like your implementation. It's the same as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7290026/813665). Do you think it's better to use `conj` or `merge` for `merge-with`?

Answer (score 8):

You could use a list comprehension and some destructuring, like

```
user=> (->> (for [[day consum] data 
  #_=>            [fruit amount] consum]
  #_=>         {fruit {day amount}})
  #_=>      (apply merge-with conj))
{:orange {:tuesday 2}, :banana {:tuesday 5, :monday 2}, :apple {:monday 3}}
user=>
```

or using a function + `mapcat` instead:

```
(defn flip [[day consum]]
    (map (fn [[fruit amount]] {fruit {day amount}}) consum))

(apply merge-with conj (mapcat flip data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
(defn map-reverse-hierarchy [m]
  (let [foo (fn [a lst]
              (map #(do [(first %) {a (second %)}]) lst))
        bbb (map (fn [[a b]] (into {} (foo a b))) m)]
    (if (seq bbb)
      (apply merge-with merge bbb)
      {})))

(map-reverse-hierarchy {:monday {:banana 2 :apple 3} 
                        :tuesday {:banana 5 :orange 2}})

;{:banana {:monday 2, :tuesday 5}, :apple {:monday 3}, :orange {:tuesday 2}}
```

Comment: Your solution looks nice. But I am looking for something that uses clojure high-level functions instead of your `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need some custom function. Use `clojure.set/map-invert`[1] to swap keys and values in hash-map

[1] http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.set-api.html#clojure.set/map-invert

---

brute-force solution:

```
(defn x []
  (let [i {:monday {:banana 2 :apple 3}
           :tuesday {:banana 5 :orange 2}}]
    (reduce-kv (fn [h day fruits]
                 (reduce-kv (fn [h fruit n]
                              (update-in h [fruit day] #(+ (or % 0) n))) h fruits)) {} i)))

user> (pprint (x))
{:orange {:tuesday 2},
 :banana {:tuesday 5, :monday 2},
 :apple {:monday 3}}
```

Comment: thanks for your reference to `map-invert`